<large,cat-like> vs <large cat-like> vs <large and cat-like>


Pumas are large,cat-like animals which are found in America.
Pumas are large cat-like animals which are found in America.
Pumas are large and cat-like animals which are found in America.


The first sentence is from New Concept English, and I wrote the other two.  I think the common style is as (2), with the two modifiers directly stacking one on top of another, without a comma. （3）can also be seen occasionally.
Are they mean roughly the same thing in this case?  What is the nuance？

There is no 'nuance'; the different versions are examples of style choice.

A puma is not just "cat-like".  A puma is literally a cat - the common name for any animal in the Felidae family. So, "cat-like animals" seems to be redundant. I think it would be more natural to say "Pumas are large cats ... "

@BillyKerr - Indeed - but most dictionaries give 'small domestic animal...' as the primary definition and 'wild animal of the cat family' as a secondary one.

@KateBunting - sure, but Pumas are "large cats". Might even be better to call them "big cats", which is a commonly used term for species such as lions, tigers, pumas, leopards, jaguars.

@BillyKerr - not to mention Gandalf the Maine Coon down the road, who is undisputed ruler of the street.

Every phylogeneticist rolls their eyes if you say pumas are "big cats",  Puma are Felinae, not   Pantherinae:  not "big cats"

The OED defines "big cat" as "Any of the larger members of the cat family (Felidae), such as a lion, tiger, or leopard."   So, that would also include pumas, cougars, and cheetas which are also Felidae, and large.  Felinae and Pantherinae are sub families of Felidae.
